# Determining which Dictionary matches my dictionary class in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Refernece file : file.py

```
class requestDicts():
    dictrefA={
    "operation_module":"cbs",
    "operation_group":"xxx",
    "operation_type":"yyy"}

    dictrefB={
    "operation_module":"cbs",
    "operation_group":"xxx",
    "operation_type":"yyy1"}

    dictrefC={
    "operation_module":"cbs",
    "operation_group":"xxx1",
    "operation_type":"yyy1"}
```

comparefile head.py

```
recievedDict={
    "msg_id":100,
    "operation_module":"cbs",
    "operation_group":"xxx",
    "operation_type":"yyy1",
    "user_name":"venkat",
    "msg_length":50}
```

How to perform a partial compare dictionaries and return the name of the dictionary in which it matches

the expected answer above is : `dictrefB`

Comment: Variable name is just a reference to an object. Better create a dict of dicts here.

Comment: Or maybe even a list of dicts ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this looks more appropriate here, using a `dict` of dicts:

```
main_dict={
    'dictrefA':{
      "operation_module":"cbs",
      "operation_group":"xxx",
      "operation_type":"yyy"},
    'dictrefB':{
      "operation_module":"cbs",
      "operation_group":"xxx",
      "operation_type":"yyy1"},
    'dictrefC':{
      "operation_module":"cbs",
      "operation_group":"xxx1",
      "operation_type":"yyy1"}
      }

recievedDict={
    "msg_id":100,
    "operation_module":"cbs",
    "operation_group":"xxx",
    "operation_type":"yyy1",
    "user_name":"venkat",
    "msg_length":50}

for x,y in main_dict.items():
    if all(v in recievedDict.items() for v in y.items()):
        print x
        break
```

**output**:

```
dictrefB
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your original data, I'd create an intermediate lookup and a helper function, and go for something like:

```
from operator import itemgetter

key = itemgetter('operation_module', 'operation_group', 'operation_type')
lookup = {key(v): k for k,v in requestDicts.__dict__.iteritems() if isinstance(v, dict)}
print lookup[key(recievedDict)]
```

Comment: @mgilson yeah - fancied a change :)

Comment: I think that `viewitems` (or just `items` on py3k) is the best way to go about this.  It's a little frustrating because `view` aren't actual `sets`, so I can't use `issubset`, but that's OK -- Tests for length works too.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

On python2.7 and python3.x, there is a better way:

```
items = ((k,v) for (k,v) in requestDicts.__dict__.items() if k.startswith('dictref'))
r_items = recievedDict.viewitems()
print next(k for k,sub in items if len(sub.viewitems() & r_items) == len(sub))
```

The first line is just an attempt at putting your class-holding-dictionaries into a slightly more useful data-structure.  The second line is simply to shorten the third line and to avoid an extra attribute-lookup/method call in the generator.

On python3.x, `dict.items` returns the same thing that `dict.viewitems` did in python2.x.  I assume that `2to3` will understand that.  Basically, the `view` returns the items as a set-like object.  I get the intersection of the two sets and check to make sure that it is a complete intersection.  In other words, I check to make sure that the one dictionary is a subset of the other.  I don't guarantee that this is more *efficient* than my other answer, but it is a bit more concise (and I wouldn't be surprised if it is faster).  I suppose we'd need to `timeit` to know.

---

I don't see any better way than looping to compare them:

```
def compare(sub,full):
    try:
        return all(sub[k] == full[k] for k in sub)
    except KeyError:
        return False  #sub's keys aren't a subset of full's keys.
```

Now to figure out which is the first match:

```
next(sub for sub in (dictrefA,dictrefB,dictrefC) if compare(sub,recievedDict))
```

Here's a full, concrete working example:

```
class requestDicts():
    dictrefA={
    "operation_module":"cbs",
    "operation_group":"xxx",
    "operation_type":"yyy"}

    dictrefB={
    "operation_module":"cbs",
    "operation_group":"xxx",
    "operation_type":"yyy1"}

    dictrefC={
    "operation_module":"cbs",
    "operation_group":"xxx1",
    "operation_type":"yyy1"}

recievedDict={
    "msg_id":100,
    "operation_module":"cbs",
    "operation_group":"xxx",
    "operation_type":"yyy1",
    "user_name":"venkat",
    "msg_length":50}


def compare(sub,full):
    try:
        return all(sub[k] == full[k] for k in sub)
    except KeyError:
        return False  #sub's keys aren't a subset of full's keys.

items = ((k,v) for (k,v) in requestDicts.__dict__.items() if k.startswith('dictref'))
print next(k for k,sub in items if compare(sub,recievedDict))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main_dict={
    'dictrefA':{
      "operation_module":"cbs",
      "operation_group":"xxx",
      "operation_type":"yyy"},
    'dictrefB':{
      "operation_module":"cbs",
      "operation_group":"xxx",
      "operation_type":"yyy1"},
    'dictrefC':{
      "operation_module":"cbs",
      "operation_group":"xxx1",
      "operation_type":"yyy1"}
      }
recieved_dict={
    "msg_id":100,
    "operation_module":"cbs",
    "operation_group":"xxx",
    "operation_type":"yyy1",
    "user_name":"venkat",
    "msg_length":50}

compare_dict = {
    "operation_module": recieved_dict["operation_module"],
    "operation_group": recieved_dict["operation_group"],
    "operation_type": recieved_dict["operation_type"],
}

matching_dict_key = [key for key, value in main_dict.items() if value == compare_dict]

print matching_dict_key[0]
```

Result:

```
$ python so.py
dictrefB
```

If it needs to be faster, you could make a dictionary of hashes.